# What is the purpose of JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE in JavaCC?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javacc

What is the purpose of JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE in JavaCC, I have looked at the documentation and it explains it very vaguely.

Comment: In one sense the purpose was to make it easy to write parsers for Java and Java-like languages such as JavaCC itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the [documentation](https://javacc.org/javaccgrm) says:

> JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE: This is a boolean option whose default value is false. When set to true, the generated parser uses an input stream object that processes Java Unicode escapes (\u...) before sending characters to the token manager. By default, Java Unicode escapes are not processed.

What does that mean?

A Java Unicode escape is a sequence starting with `\u` and followed by 4 hexadecimal digits.  In normal Java, such a sequence is translated into a UTF-16 codeunit.  This translation happens *before* tokenization, as described in [JLS 3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3).  (And as the JLS explains, Unicode codepoints that are not in the basic code plain need to be represented as two escape sequences representing the UTF-16 surrogate pair for the Unicode codepoint.)

So the `JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE` option basically tells JavaCC whether or not the *generated lexer / parser* should do Unicode escape handling in the same way as a Java compiler does.  The default is to not handle the `\uxxxx` escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks very much. Could handling `\uxxxx` cause any problems?

Comment: I don't see why it would.  But it kind of implies that the language you are implementing allows this escaping in its source code.  It also implies that your compiler will do something sensible with the Unicode codepoints that result from decoding the escapes.

Comment: Could it cause problems?  Sure.  Suppose you use it for a C compiler.  The string literal `"\\u1234" will be treated incorrectly.

Comment: See the 2nd sentence of my last comment. Obviously, if the language you are implementing doesn't allow Unicode escapes, then enabling them in the grammar is incorrect.  But I would call that a mistake ... not a problem.